# Can I pass data to blade component by used curly braces?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to implement kind of a feature toggle to use with my components. I am wondering if it is possible to pass data to components by evaluating it with {{ }} something like in:

```
The current UNIX timestamp is {{ time() }}.
```

Here is my code:
The component

```
<x-share-on-social-media :isOn="{{FeatureToggleUtility::isOn('share-on-social-media')}}"/>
```

The component class

```
class ShareOnSocialMedia extends Component {

public $isOn;

/**
 * Create a new component instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($isOn) {
        $this->isOn = $isOn;
    } 
.... 
}
```

I get the following error:

```
ParseError
syntax error, unexpected token "<" (View: /....../resources/views/offer.blade.php)
http://localhost:8899/offer/30
```

Comment: Add the code of your `/resources/views/offer.blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

To pass the actual variable to blade component you don't need to use curly braces while passing.

Adding `:` before the attribute will be passed as variable.

```
<x-share-on-social-media :isOn="FeatureToggleUtility::isOn('share-on-social-media')"/>
```

You can read more about it [here on docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components)